# Combining lowest frequencies in Huffman Coding

Tags: tree, huffman-code

I'm reviewing for my final exam and I'm currently focusing on Huffman coding.

As I understand.. you take the two lowest frequencies and combine them.. building the tree from the bottom up.

My question is.. what do you do when 3 or more frequencies are the same? Does it matter which two you select to combine? Do you combine all of them?

Does the order of letters matter? Like obviously after you do the encoding part, the letters could be different depending on which you choose.

I found several tutorials and examples online, but none seem to demonstrate this scenario. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

---

### EXAMPLE:

Say i'm given an array of letters as such: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g] with the following frequencies:

a=3 b=2 c=6 d=2 e=4 f=2 g=4

Comment: Before I tell you what I think, Do you understand why Huffman encoding works and _why_ you combine the lowest frequencies in the first place?  If you do, try to reflect on that and see if an answer naturally comes to you.  here's a sample for you to play with:  `a:0.245 b:0.245 c:0.245 d:0.265`

Comment: @SamIam You combine the lowest frequencies first because they'll end up at the bottom of the tree since they are accessed the least often. With your example.. the tree would have the top parent be 1 with its right child as .34 and then the left of 1.. would be .66 with left and right children being .33 each. Is that right?

Comment: yeah, that's right.  I've updated the sample to be more relevant to your question though.

Comment: the point is that you might not want to be so dependent on people telling you what to do in every scenario that comes up.  If you think about what huffman encoding actually does, the answer to this question should come to you fairly easily

Comment: @SamIam ok I've drawn it out on a dry erase board. I got a tree with parent .49 and .245,.245 as children. And another tree with .51 as parent and .245,.265 as children. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @SamIam would I just add the root parent as 1.. and the left child be the .49 tree and the right child be the .51 tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pick 2.  Any 2.  It doesn't matter which 2 you pick.  The only meaningful metric here is their frequency, and the frequencies are all the same regardless of which 2 you pick.

You can't combine all 3 of them.

Remember, a Huffman tree is a binary tree because each branch corresponds to bits: `0` and `1`.  It doesn't make any sense for a Huffman tree to have 3 branches, because you don't have 3 different kinds of bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine all of them.  Combine two and repeat. If you combine all of them you need a complete new logic, for example ternary, quads etc.